# SvelteKit - runtime configuration file on production

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, svelte, sveltekit

Svelte + SvelteKit web app, hosted with Node.js

Is it possible to somehow use `.env` or any other configuration file on production build in SvelteKit? I need some values to be modifiable during runtime both on server and client side. Something akin to `appsettings.json` in .NET.

After `npm run build`, the outputted `build` folder is moved from repo to another location on drive

Tried using `$env/dynamic/public` ([link to SvelteKit documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-dynamic-public)), can't figure out how it's supposed to work. Creating an `.env` file in my `build` folder doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Please note that environment variables are not loaded by default with the Node adapter.

[Docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node#environment-variables):

> In `dev` and `preview`, SvelteKit will read environment variables from your `.env` file (or `.env.local`, or `.env.[mode]`, [as determined by Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files).)
>
> In production, `.env` files are not automatically loaded. To do so, install dotenv in your project...
>
> ```bash
> npm install dotenv
> ```
>
> ...and invoke it before running the built app:
>
> ```bash
> node -r dotenv/config build
> ```